# How to use sum function in a subquery?

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I am using a IBM DB2 DBMS and I would like to show the total amount paid per client. Currently when I select all, it will show me multiple pay amounts per clients and this leads to repeating clients.

I would like to show the total amount paid per client, against an arbitrary number that is not in my table.

This is what I have thus far. I am getting an error with my subquery.

```
SELECT T1.CLIENT_ID 
    (SELECT SUM(T2.PAY_AMT) FROM AR_SUM T2 WHERE T1.CLIENT_ID = T2.CLIENT_ID) AS TOTAL
    FROM AR_SUM T1
    GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

I would like it to show:

```
Client_ID     TOTAL
abc           100
def           200
ghi           150
```

As I mentioned earlier, I would like to compare that to an arbitrary goal amount that is not in my table. Also, is there a way to translate that to a percentage?

My end product I would like:

```
Client_ID     TOTAL     percent of total <-- (lets say out of 100)
abc           10        .10 or 10% <-- if possible 
def           20        .2
ghi           15        .15
```

Comment: It might be easier to put your 'arbitrary' numbers in a table. Then join the tables.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have the administrative privileges to create or edit tables

Answer (score 0):

As written, your query is missing a comma:

```
SELECT T1.CLIENT_ID,
-------------------^
       (SELECT SUM(T2.PAY_AMT) 
        FROM AR_SUM T2 
        WHERE T1.CLIENT_ID = T2.CLIENT_ID) AS TOTAL
FROM AR_SUM T1
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

But it is simpler to use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT T.CLIENT_ID, SUM(T.PAY_AMT) AS TOTAL
FROM AR_SUM T
GROUP BY t.CLIENT_ID
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: WOW A COMMA! I keep getting errors with Select SUM, but the first one worked.